# Broken images in old questions

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, images

I just revisited an [old question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3039254/87698) and noticed that both the image embedded in my question as well as the one embedded in one of the answers have been replaced by some strange tinypic link.

It's been a long time, but I'm pretty sure that the images were embedded back in 2010. The change history does not show any relevant changes.

Here are some screenshots; just in case it's caused by something on my side:

[image: Question]
[image: Answer]

Comment: What is "declined" here, @Martijn? Seems like [status-bydesign] would be more appropriate. Or changing the tag to [support].

Comment: @CodyGray: I felt 'by design' didn't fit, but on further reflection on what is going on here it does. It's actually the HTTPS switch that caused this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You used an external image host that serves images over (unencrypted) HTTP; with the switch from HTTP to HTTPS those links were not updated (and can't be updated, Stack Overflow can't know what external services can handle HTTPS now or in the future).

Images are not 'embedded', they are loaded from a URL pointing to the actual image, on a different server. But to be able to serve Stack Overflow over HTTPS, you can no longer serve images over HTTP as that'd allow an attacker to bypass the security offered by encrypting the site in the first place.

So until the image can be re-hosted, the image is replaced by a link instead, so that you can still access the image.

If you edit your post, and look at the preview, the images are auto-marked as in need of editing:

> [image: https image editing warning]

Click on the 'upload' link to pre-fill the URL into the upload dialog, to move the image to the Stack Overflow image host (which serves those images over HTTPS).

Note that if the external server (tinypic.com here) stops serving an image on the given URL, there is nothing to display anymore. It is always a better idea to use the Stack Overflow image host; other image hosters delete images outright after a while. One even replaced images with advertisements.

Comment: Thanks, I downloaded and re-uploaded the images using the built-in uploader. In my defense: back then, there was no included image uploader, and tinypic was *probably* one of the recommended services (not sure about the latter point, it's been a long time).

Comment: @Heinzi: fair enough, the service was added in [August 2010](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/18/new-image-upload-support/), your affected post predates by 3 months.

Comment: @Heinzi: I discovered this is more of a https vs http issue.

Comment: @Heinzi: re-written to reflect what is actually going on.

Comment: Ah, makes sense, thanks for the update!